# spring-data mongo repository. Is saveAll atomic?

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot

I have a feeling that

```
org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository#saveAll
/*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * @see org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository#saveAll(java.lang.Iterable)
     */
    @Override
    <S extends T> List<S> saveAll(Iterable<S> entities);
```

is not atomic, is it true? It it possible to saveAll in single batch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not. It saves in batch only "new" documents (checks by id). It saves existing documents (id is in collection) one by one.

Answer (score 0):

No, according to its implementation it is not;
Implementation:

```
@Override
public <S extends T> List<S> saveAll(Iterable<S> entities) {

   Assert.notNull(entities, "The given Iterable of entities not be null!");

   Streamable<S> source = Streamable.of(entities);
   boolean allNew = source.stream().allMatch(entityInformation::isNew);

   if (allNew) {

      List<S> result = source.stream().collect(Collectors.toList());
      return new ArrayList<>(mongoOperations.insert(result, entityInformation.getCollectionName()));
   }

   return source.stream().map(this::save).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```